# How can I paste unique values to certain cells in specified workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a particular problem so sorry for the bad title. I am trying to paste corresponding values from a different workbook to my current workbook based on some criteria. However, the problem is, some of the cells in some workbooks are supposed to be empty but the code fills them with the values of the previous worksheets. Here is my code:

```
Sub Button5_Click()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim k As String
    Dim wsisim As String
    Dim namen As String

    For j = 18 To 277
        For i = 2 To 338
            wsisim = Workbooks("2019 Actual Tinker").Worksheets(j).Name
            namen = Right(wsisim, 4)
        Do While Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 2).Value = namen And i < 339
            If Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Müdür" Then
                mudmaas = Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 24).Value
                mudprim = Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 25).Value
            ElseIf Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Yönetici" Then
                yonmaas = Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 24).Value
                yonprim = Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 25).Value
            ElseIf Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 4).Value = "TL" Then
                TLmaas = Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 24).Value
                tlprim = Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)").Cells(i, 25).Value
            End If
            lnt = Len(wsisim)
            ostotmaas = mudmaas + yonmaas
            TotPrim = mudprim + yonprim + tlprim

            k = CStr(TotPrim)          

            Workbooks("2019 Actual Tinker").Worksheets(j).Range("I51").Value = ostotmaas
            Workbooks("2019 Actual Tinker").Worksheets(j).Range("I52").Value = TLmaas            

            Workbooks("2019 Actual Tinker").Worksheets(j).Range("I50").FormulaLocal = "=+'\\ccfs1\Mali Isler\MIS\2019 Actual\Actual Navigator\[2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz.xlsx]" & Left(Worksheets(j).Name, lnt - 4) & "'!$E$39-I52-I51" & "+" & k
            Workbooks("2019 Actual Tinker").Worksheets(j).Range("I55").FormulaLocal = "=+'\\ccfs1\Mali Isler\MIS\2019 Actual\Actual Navigator\[2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz.xlsx]" & Left(Worksheets(j).Name, lnt - 4) & "'!$E$44" & "-" & k

            i = i + 1        
        Loop        
        Next i
        i = 2
    Next j

End Sub
```

I have tried setting `ostotmaas` and `Totprim` to zero after each while loop i.e. after the `i = i + 1` line. But it did not work either because the "Ağustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker" workbook is quite messy and sometimes has required values in separate rows so setting the variables to zero causes some of the cells that are supposed to be filled to be empty. I cannot think of a logical approach method. Please help.

Comment: Hello @KKB. Try sitting "mudmaas", "yonmaas", "mudprim", "yonprim", and "tlprim" to 0 after each loop. Note that you do not need the while loop if you are using the for loop, and vice-versa you do not need the for loop if you are using the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many loops. You only need one, to loop through the worksheets. Then use `Find` method to locate the correct row.

Also you should use variables for the worksheets, as you refer to them many times. This will speed up your code and will make it more readable.

Try this and tell me if it does what you want.

```
Sub Button5_Click()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim k As String
Dim wsisim As String
Dim namen As String

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Aðustos 19 Tahk ve Rpr Tinker").Worksheets("Primler (2)")
    For j = 18 To 277
        Set ws2 = Workbooks("2019 Actual Tinker").Worksheets(j)
        wsisim = ws2.Name
        namen = Right(wsisim, 4)
        Set rng = ws1.Range("B2:B338").Find(namen, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox namen & " not found"
        Else
            If ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value = "Mudur" Then
                mudmaas = ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 24).Value
                mudprim = ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 25).Value
            ElseIf ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value = "Yonetici" Then
                yonmaas = ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 24).Value
                yonprim = ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 25).Value
            ElseIf ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value = "TL" Then
                TLmaas = ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 24).Value
                tlprim = ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 25).Value
            End If
            Set rng = Nothing
        End If
        lnt = Len(wsisim)
        ostotmaas = mudmaas + yonmaas
        TotPrim = mudprim + yonprim + tlprim
        k = CStr(TotPrim)

        ws2.Range("I51").Value = ostotmaas
        ws2.Range("I52").Value = TLmaas
        ws2.Range("I50").FormulaLocal = "=+'\\ccfs1\Mali Isler\MIS\2019 Actual\Actual Navigator\[2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz.xlsx]" & Left(Worksheets(j).Name, lnt - 4) & "'!$E$39-I52-I51" & "+" & k
        ws2.Range("I55").FormulaLocal = "=+'\\ccfs1\Mali Isler\MIS\2019 Actual\Actual Navigator\[2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz.xlsx]" & Left(Worksheets(j).Name, lnt - 4) & "'!$E$44" & "-" & k
    Next j
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This does not write ostotmaas and TLmaas. And after a while, it gives an application defined or object defined error.

Comment: give some more information. what exactly goes wrong? it does not write anything at all? it writes something in a wrong place? when exactly throws the error? which line is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: The error is not the problem I guess I can fix that. The problem is that your code does not write the values of ostotmaas and TLmaas to the required cells. Thank you for your concern though, as I said before, this is too specific of a problem to be answered here. I guess I'm gonna have to figure it out myself. I'll let you know when I do, if you're still interested.